# Android connects to server receives text and display it on the textview

Tags: c#, android

The current app reads a textfile and by every button click it displays the first element of the line and if the button were clicked again the second element of the line display to another textview and so on. I want to let the app do the same thing but it should first connect to the server and if the connection is there it should display the first element of the line and then the second element. Can someone help? Im a beginner.

Android site:

```
package com.example.hartmann.anlage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int countPresses = 0;
//String lines;
String lines = "";
String kugelgroesse ="";
String first ="";
String second ="";
String third ="";
String[] line = new String[4];
int firstsumme = 0;
int secondsumme = 0;
int thirdsumme = 0;
int summe = 0;
String delete = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView TextDisk1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextDisk1);
    final TextView TextDisk2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextDisk2);
    final TextView TextDisk3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextDisk3);
    final TextView TextDisk4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextDisk4);
    final TextView TextDisk5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextDisk5);
    final TextView _TextDisk3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = getAssets().open("Messwerte.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    final BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);


   // int countPresses = 0;

    assert button != null;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (countPresses % 3 == 0) {
                Log.d("Zeile", "lesen");
                // Zeile lesen
                try {
                    lines = buffer.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                line = lines.split("\t");
                kugelgroesse = line[0];
                first = line[1];
                second = line[2];
                third = line[3];
                firstsumme = Integer.parseInt(first) + Integer.parseInt(second) + Integer.parseInt(third);
                secondsumme = Integer.parseInt(second) + Integer.parseInt(third);
                thirdsumme = Integer.parseInt(third);
                summe = Integer.parseInt(first) + Integer.parseInt(second) + Integer.parseInt(third);
                WriteText(_TextDisk3, (kugelgroesse));
                WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(summe));
            }


            // Anzeige
            Log.d("Anzeigen","");
            String string = line[countPresses % 3 + 1];
            //WriteText(_TextDisk3, kugelgroesse);
            //WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(summe));


            Random random = new Random();
            int value = random.nextInt();

            switch (kugelgroesse) {
                case "40":
                    if (first == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(firstsumme));
                    } else if (second == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(secondsumme));
                    } else if (third == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(thirdsumme));
                    }

                    break;

                case "100":
                    if (first == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(firstsumme));
                    } else if (second == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(secondsumme));
                    } else if (third == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(thirdsumme));
                    }
                    break;

                case "60":
                    if (first == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(firstsumme));
                    } else if (second == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(secondsumme));
                    } else if (third == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(thirdsumme));
                    }
                    break;

                case "80":
                    if (first == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(firstsumme));
                    } else if (second == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(secondsumme));
                    } else if (third == string) {
                        WriteText(TextDisk4, string);
                        WriteText(TextDisk5, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk1, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk2, delete);
                        WriteText(TextDisk3, Integer.toString(thirdsumme));
                    }
                    break;
            }
            countPresses++;
            //try {
                //Thread.sleep(3000);
            //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            //}
        }
    });

}


public void WriteText(final TextView textView, final String value){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(value);
        }
    });
}
 }
```

Server site:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.IO;

namespace RanServer
{


public partial class Server : Form
{
    public delegate void TextManagerDelegate(string text);
    public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public List<StateObject> list = new List<StateObject>();

    public Socket listener;

    TextManagerDelegate TextHandler;
    private const int port = 15000;
    StreamReader reader;
    int counter = 0;
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("G:\\Neu\\MesswerteAnlage.txt");


    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextHandler = new TextManagerDelegate(TextManager);
        StartListening();


    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.Resolve("localhost").AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            ShowText.AppendText("\nServer is connected "+ localEndPoint + Environment.NewLine);
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(1000);

            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            ShowText.AppendText("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

    }

    // AcceptCallback is called when a client wants to connect
    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;

        list.Add(state);

        BeginInvoke(TextHandler,"\nNew connection established.");

        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }

    // ReadCallback wird aufgerufen, wenn der Client Daten an den Server geschickt hat
    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = String.Empty;

            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            BeginInvoke(TextHandler, ("\nVerbindung zum Client überprüfen!"));

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                BeginInvoke(TextHandler, ("Received " + bytesRead + " bytes from socket: " + data));

                // Der Stringbuilder im StateObjekt (state.sb) wurde vorgesehen falls der buffer nicht ausreicht, um alle Bytes
                // auf einmal zu erhalten. Dann werden die Daten zerstückelt und auf mehrere Messages aufgeteilt.
                // Der Stringbuilder baut diese wieder in einen String zusammen.

                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(data);

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                BeginInvoke(TextHandler, ("Total read " + content.Length + " bytes from socket. \n Data : " + content));

                // Für Testzwecke kann man die empfangenen Daten an den Client zurückschicken
                //Send(handler, content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception q)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(q.Message);
        }

    }


    // SendCallback is called when the server has sends data to the client
    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            //BeginInvoke(TextHandler,("Sent " + bytesSent + " bytes to client(" + RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(handler)+ ")."));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    //Stops the connection and close the server 
    private void StopButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Iteriere durch Stateobject-Liste und schließe die einzelnen Sockets
        foreach (StateObject state in list)
        {
            // Löse die verbindung auf
            state.workSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            state.workSocket.Close();
            list.Remove(state);
        }

        listener.Close();
    }

    private void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            BeginInvoke(TextHandler, ("Send data to: " + RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(handler)));
            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);



    }

    //If the button is clicked
    public void SendFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Iteriere durch Stateobject-Liste und schicke an jeden die entsprechenden Daten

        foreach (StateObject state in list)
        {
            string line;
            line = lines[counter];

            //string data = "foo";
            // den string mit dem Inhalt der jeweiligen nächsten Zeile befüllen
            // die letzte ZeilenNr ist in state.zeilenVerschickt drinnen

            Send(state.workSocket, line);
            //state.zeilenVerschickt++;

        }
        counter++;


    }
    public void TextManager(string txt)
    {
        ShowText.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + txt );
    }
}
// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // mitzählen der Anzahl der verschickten Zeilen
    //public int zeilenVerschickt = 0;

}


}
```

Comment: What is an element of a line? Never heard of that.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry if it wasnt clear enought. For example the line starts like that 40 2 1 6 the first element that i meant is number 2 and the second is 1 and the third is 6

Comment: Isn't 40 the first one then?

Comment: yeah i know :D but there are other reasons why i didnt called it first element

Comment: So now you are reading lines from a text file from assets. Then you do all kinds of things with the numbers in the line. That fidling around with numbers is irrelevant for your problem. But it is a lot of code. Why should we read that code? The only thing you want to change is how you read lines from a server. What you do with lines is irrelevant. So please remove the irrelevant code so we can concentrate on the problem.

Comment: It is funny that you use `runOnUiThread()` as it is not needed now. But it will be usefull if you read data from server in a Thread or AsyncTask.